# Looping through two different selectors at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery to calculate some totals figures and I have run into a problem.

Let's say I have two sets of inputs, each with a unique name.

```
$('[name="quantity\\[\\]"]')
$('[name="price\\[\\]"]')
```

I want to cycle through each set of inputs at the same time so that I can check both for (!isNaN) and (length !== 0), and if the values are valid, I want to multiply them together and add to a running total.

I know I can cycle through one selector using each(), but how can I cycle through two at the same time? is there an elegant way to accomplish this goal?

Comment: Are there equal numbers of both sets of inputs? Can you show the mark-up you're working with? Perhaps a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Do these fields appear in pairs on the page?

Comment: @David Thomas @Šime Vidas yes they appear in pairs, and there is always an equal number of both inputs.

Comment: If they're located inside a common container, you could iterate over all the containers and for each iteration (container) grab the two values inside it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var prices = $('[name="price\\[\\]"]');
$('[name="quantity\\[\\]"]').each(function(i){
  var quantity = this;
  var price    = prices[i];
  // Compare them here.
});
```

Answer (score 3):

All cute things jQuery aside, here is a generic "zip" function.

`a` and `b` should be arrays (or at least array-like). If `fn` is supplied this will act as a *map* over each *pair* of items. Remember that jQuery objects *are* arrays.

```
function zip (a, b, fn) {
   var len = Math.max(a.length, b.length)
   var result = []
   if (fn) {
     for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
       result.push(fn(a[i], b[i]))
     }
   } else {
     for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
       result.push([a[i], b[i]])
     }
   }
   return result
}
```

Example:

```
var z = zip([1,2,3], ['a','b'])
// z = [[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,undefined]
for (var i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    var elm = z[i]
    var a = elm[0]
    var b = elm[1]
    alert(a + "-" + b)
}
```

Example with `fn`:

```
zip([1,2,3], ['a','b'], function (a, b) {
    alert(a + "-" + b)
})
```

Example in jQuery'ish context:

```
var total = 0
zip(
  $('[name="quantity\\[\\]"]'),
  $('[name="price\\[\\]"]'),
  function (a, b) {
    // if either a or b are undefined, there is already a problem
    // the `expr || 0` is to silently handle cases of `NaN || 0` which may
    // result if the price or quantity are garbage values
    var qty = parseInt($(a).val(), 10) || 0
    var price = parseInt($(b).val(), 10) || 0
    total += qty * price
  })
```

Happy coding.

Comment: Nice functions, but you're missing quite a few semicolons `:(`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a straight forward solution

```
var quantities = $('[name="quantity\\[\\]"]'),
    prices = $('[name="price\\[\\]"]');


var len = Math.max(quantities.size(), prices.size());
for (var i=0; i < len; i++) {
  var quantity = quantities.get(i);
  var price = prices.get(i);
  // Do whatever you want with quantity and price    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the result of the selection in a variable, and use the `index` argument for the `each` when enumerating to reference the related element in the other set.

```
var quan = $('[name="quantity\\[\\]"]');
var price = $('[name="price\\[\\]"]');
var total = 0;

quan.each(function( index ) {
    var quan_val = +$(this).val();
    var price_val = +price.eq( index ).val();

    if( quan_val && price_val ) {
        total += (quan_val * price_val);
    }
});

alert( total );
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
function getValue() { return this.value; }

var valsA = $('input[name="quantity\\[\\]"]').map(getValue).get(),
    valsB = $('input[name="price\\[\\]"]').map(getValue).get();

for ( var i = 0; i < valsA.length; i++ ) {
    // work with valsA[i] and valsB[i] here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a comma:

```
$('[name="quantity\\[\\]"], [name="price\\[\\]"]')
```

Comment: (+1) it will help selector performance a lot if an element type is provided as well, e.g. `$('input[name="quantity\\[\\]"], input[name="price\\[\\]"]')`

Comment: @Matt I don't think the OP wants to cycle trough the sets sequentially. I think he wants to cycle trough *both* sets concurrently...

Comment: @Šime Vidas is right. I don't want to cycle through one, then the other. I need both values from each input type at the same time during each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

loop and use the index

```
var quantity = $('[name="quantity\\[\\]"]')
$('[name="price\\[\\]"]').each( function(ind){
    var currentPrice = $(this);
    var currentQuantity = quantity.eq(ind);
});
```

or something like

```
$('[name="price\\[\\]"]').each( function(ind){
    var currentPrice = $(this);
    var currentQuantity = currentPrice.closest('[name="quantity\\[\\]"]');
});
```